# Secondary expansion in a Makefile is causing unnecessary targets to be run

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, expansion, indirection

I am trying to write a Makefile that builds PDF outputs with LaTeX, using Latexmk. The outputs have basically the same rule, with different prerequisites, so I tried generalising my original Makefile using GNU Make's "secondary expansion". (I also created `.PHONY` targets, also with secondary expansion, to make it more user-friendly.) However, this is causing the prerequisite rules to *always* be run, even when they don't need to be. Fortunately, Latexmk is clever enough to avoid doing unnecessary work, but I wonder if I'm doing anything wrong...

To try to abstract what I'm attempting:

```
      ,-> foo -> build/foo.pdf
all -{
      `-> bar -> build/bar.pdf
```

That is, the `all` target builds `foo` and `bar`. These targets open the respective PDF file, which have a prerequisite of `build/X.pdf` (where `X` is `foo` or `bar`). These are genuine targets which build the appropriate PDF file.

This is what I've come up with:

```
TARGETS   = foo bar
BUILD_DIR = build
OUTPUTS   = $(TARGETS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.pdf)

commonSRC = src/preamble.tex src/header.tex # etc...
fooSRC    = src/foo.tex $(commonSRC) # etc...
barSRC    = src/bar.tex $(commonSRC) # etc...

all: $(TARGETS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TARGETS): $(BUILD_DIR)/$$@.pdf
    open $<

# FIXME This isn't quite right: This rule is still getting called by the
# above rule, even when it doesn't need to be. Latexmk is clever enough
# not to do any extra work, but it shouldn't run at all.
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OUTPUTS): $$($$(subst .pdf,SRC,$$(@F))) $(BUILD_DIR)
    latexmk -outdir=$(BUILD_DIR) -auxdir=$(BUILD_DIR) -pdf $<

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

.PHONY: all $(TARGETS) clean
```

Just to be clear: The rule for `build/X.pdf` should run whenever the files enumerated in `XSRC` (again, where `X` is `foo` or `bar`) are newer than the PDFs, or the PDFs don't exist; but it should not run otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this got somewhat complex, more than it needs to be. Part of these second expansion statements can be just replaced with [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). The other thing is that `.SECONDEXPANSION:` makes all further `Makefile` contents to be subject to [second expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), so you don't need to explicitly state it before every target (it would be much clearer to mark `.PHONY` targets this way to quickly see if a target is phony or not).

Nevertheless, I believe that most important issue here is that you mention a directory as a prerequisite. Remember that `make` decides on whether to rebuild the target based on dependencies timestamp, and a directory gets its timestamp always updated whenever a file in this directory is updated. Therefore, whenever you write `$(BUILD_DIR)/foo.pdf`, `$(BUILD_DIR)` timestamp gets updated and the next call will build again since the directory is newer. You can avoid it by specifying a directory as an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) (which means: build if it doesn't exist, but do not check timestamp).

Putting it all together I would make it this way:

```
TARGETS   = foo bar
BUILD_DIR = build

commonSRC = src/preamble.tex src/header.tex # etc...
fooSRC    = src/foo.tex $(commonSRC) # etc...
barSRC    = src/bar.tex $(commonSRC) # etc...

.SECONDEXPANSION:

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS)

.PHONY: $(TARGETS)
$(TARGETS): %: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.pdf
        echo open $<

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.pdf: $$($$*SRC) | $(BUILD_DIR)
        echo latexmk -outdir=$(BUILD_DIR) -auxdir=$(BUILD_DIR) -pdf $< > $@

$(BUILD_DIR):
        mkdir -p $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
```

Output:

```
$ make all
mkdir -p build
echo latexmk -outdir=build -auxdir=build -pdf src/foo.tex > build/foo.pdf
echo open build/foo.pdf
open build/foo.pdf
echo latexmk -outdir=build -auxdir=build -pdf src/bar.tex > build/bar.pdf
echo open build/bar.pdf
open build/bar.pdf

$ make all
echo open build/foo.pdf
open build/foo.pdf
echo open build/bar.pdf
open build/bar.pdf
```

Note that subsequent call did not attempt to build anything, just open the pdf. It still reacts on the file change however:

```
$ touch src/foo.tex
$ make all
echo latexmk -outdir=build -auxdir=build -pdf src/foo.tex > build/foo.pdf
echo open build/foo.pdf
open build/foo.pdf
echo open build/bar.pdf
open build/bar.pdf

$ touch src/header.tex
$ make all
echo latexmk -outdir=build -auxdir=build -pdf src/foo.tex > build/foo.pdf
echo open build/foo.pdf
open build/foo.pdf
echo latexmk -outdir=build -auxdir=build -pdf src/bar.tex > build/bar.pdf
echo open build/bar.pdf
open build/bar.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks :) Besides "order-only prerequisites", I've never seen a rule like `$(TARGETS): %: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.pdf`, with an extra bit between the target and prerequisites. What's that called, so I can read about it in the manual?

Comment: Found it: “Static Pattern Rules”

Comment: Glad you found it. I linked it in the answer.